# How to get element by id of previous page after using window.history.back()?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I get element by id of previous page after using windows.history.back()?

Comment: When you say back, I'm assuming the whole page is re-loaded and your element is no longer in the DOM? Please explain why you need this and show what you have already tried. Currently this question doesn't make much sense because an element that's not in the DOM cannot be retrieved by querying the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Save it in local storage on the first page

```
localStorage.setItem('item', $('#elementID').val());
```

Then retrieve it from the second

```
localStorage.getItem('item');
```

Comment: That's not what's being asked, you are jus storing and item's value. OP wants to access an element that is no longer in the DOM